# Error when displaying something in a port with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I was going through an ExpressJS course and I went to the website and went to the "hello world" section. I copied and pasted the below-given code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Yes exactly that, but when I try to run it with Node it shows the following error

```
C:\Users\blue fury\my-express-server\app.js:1
��c


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I tried searching Google but found only one thread on Github which just says to restart everything (I tried but it did not work)

Comment: have you installed Express as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, if you hadn't installed express module yet, run the command : npm install --save express

in case it still does not work :

- if you created your app.js file through a command line, try to create another file by clicking the NEW FILE button on whatever IDE you are using, and copy paste that code inside of it, then try to run the new file (node NEWFILE.js), because that could be related to different encoding problem.
  let us know how it goes.

Comment: Oh so tht's the problem? I wil check it out as soon as I can and then reply.

Comment: Hey there it worked! I just copied the code and created a new file from the file explorer. @Animine.A.G

Comment: Hey @Harshanth , glad I could help :) , good luck with the rest . Peace !

Answer (score 1):

actually first you need to install exprees module
you can do that by typing
npm install express